# Test python package installation from local files

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, easy-install, pypi

I would like to start testing the installation of individual python packages (tar.gz, egg, wheel) before uploading to pypi.  That is, I'd like something like the following flow:

Build like this:

```
cd /path/to/mypkg
python setup.py sdist bdist_egg bdist_wheel
```

Then perhaps in another terminal:

```
pyvenv installtest
pip install /path/to/mypkg/dist/mypkg-0.1.2.tar.gz
```

pip doesn't permit installation from files (I think).

The closest I've found that doesn't quite work is:

```
pip -v install --no-index --find-links /path/to/mkpkg/dist mypkg
```

In that case, it does discover packages in the directory, but seems to fail to install them. (That may be unrelated.)

I have seen mentions of `pip install -e <path>`, but that only works for paths to SCM installations; it doesn't work for an arbitrary python package tarball.

So, the question is: Is there a way to pip install packages from local files rather than by fetching from pypi?

Answer (score 0):

Downloading files from PyPI locally and installing them from "downloads" folder into a venv:

`pip download -d downloads -r requirements-dev.txt
virtualenv --clear -q -p python2.7 venv
./venv/bin/pip install -r requirements-dev.txt -f downloads --no-index -U`

If you can put all the packages you'd normally get from PyPI into the "downloads" directory, pip install will install packages from local files, as requested.

Comment: I get this to work With most of my packages, but not With packages with names like this one: Cython-0.28.5-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl. It seems it is expecting the names of the file in a different format like this: CherryPy-18.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl. How can I get around this and install packages with names sugesting it is a special Windows Version using the requirements file.